# Trouble understanding structs in unions

Tags: c

I'm not a novice C player, nor am I an expert in that matter. So here's my problem.
I have a union declared as this:

```
typedef union
{
    // 8-bit data
    struct
    {
        UINT16 data8bit : 8;
    };

    // 9-bit data
    struct
    {
        UINT16 data9bit : 9;
    };

    UINT16 __data;
} EXAMPLE_DATA;
```

And there is a function that goes like this:

```
SendData(EXAMPLE_DATA data)
{  
    //.....
}
```

Now here's my quesiton.
I would like to make an object of `EXAMPLE_DATA` so that when it is passed to the `SendData` function, that my data would be of `data9bit` type.

I'm really confused and I honestly don't know the answer.
Thanks.

Comment: Just use `data.data9bit = 1` or similar - take a look at [a tutorial like this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm).

Comment: The code *calling* `SendData` that you have thus far is relevant to this question, and appears to be its foundation. But that's just a guess, as your question isn't entirely clear. Assuming you have some variable `d` of type `EXAMPLE_DATA` being sent to `SendData(d)`, then `d.data9bit = 257u;`, for example, would set the proper member.

Comment: @WhozCraig That was what I was looking for! I really went head over heels about this one and it looks that I should have known that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is complicated by the fact that two of your union's members are *anonymous* structures, but the fact remains that, in principle, an object of type `EXAMPLE_DATA` contains a value for only one member -- the last one written to -- at any given time.  That member is perforce either `__data` or one of the two anonymous structures.

The structures serve merely as containers for bitfields, one each, and because they are anonymous, their members can be accessed inside the union via the syntax for accessing a member of type `EXAMPLE_DATA` itself.  Thus, if you want the member that an `EXAMPLE_DATA` currently contains to be the `data9bit` of the corresponding structure, then you might do this:

```
EXAMPLE_DATA data;

data.data9bit = 256;
```

Do note that,

- the anonymous structures may have representations larger than 16 bits
- the location of the relevant bits of each bitfield within the representation of their structures is largely at the discretion of the implementation, and in particular, it is not necessarily within the first 16 bits (where they would overlap the representation of `__data`)
- your union provides no built-in mechanism by which one can determine which member currently contains a value, so users need either to assume or to have such information conveyed to them separately.

Answer (score 0):

The type `EXAMPLE_TYPE` will always be 2 bytes (i.e. 16 bits) in size because only complete bytes can be stored and addressed.

You're free to *interpret* the value as a 9-bit value, but the size will always be a whole number of bytes.